# What is the Grails application library?

Tags: grails

In the book, The Definitive Guide to Grails 2, I see this code fragment appear only once: `<g:javascript library="application"/>` but no explanation is there to tell what the application library is and/or does. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , We know.

`<g:javascript library="application"/>` is no wonder ,and i will explain it below.

This line is speaking of JavaScript file which is named `application.js` under
`/webapp/js/application.js`.

What it does ?

Let say if you have multiple JavaScript file to use for different page of your application.Not only that , you have 30 other more JavaScript file depending on this JavaScript file .

Then how do you load it to a page? to do list them each file in each jsp file one by one ?
That sucks! But , grails alleviated this problem by using resource plugin ...which is defined under your `ApplicationResources.groovy` defined as follow :

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'js/application.js'
        resource url:'js/yourotherjavascript.js'
        resource url:'js/otherlibrary.js'

    }

    application2 {
        // point to the complied version
        resource url:'js/script_compiled.js'
    }

}
```

As  , you can see from the script "application" refers to those javascript file refered under the application definition , if u have other u can create your name space and define it below ...CHEERS~!

Answer (score 2):

It might well be the reference to the good'ol `/js/application.js` file

See the source of your rendered GSP page

Comment: I looked at the source but wasn't sure what I should be looking for. Anything in particular?

Comment: look for `application.js`. then remove `<g:javascript library="application"/>` and look again